# How do I remove the apostrophe from my request to mysql?

Tags: mysql

[image]

[image]

I would like to know how to remove the single apostrophe from my sql request. The error shows an additional single apostrophe.

Comment: This seems to be coming from your db connection implementation, what exactly is db.query doing?

Is this a custom connector that you wrote or you are using a library for it?

Comment: Add a percent to your [search] parameter value, not into Sql pattern.